# Extracting href using bs4/python3? (again)

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, hyperlink, href

sorry to repost this question. someone migrated the question to a different site, without the cookies i could not comment or edit.

i'm new to python and bs4, please go easy on me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import time, datetime, os, requests, lxml.html
import re
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

url = "https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list.php"
ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
snkr = requests.get(url,headers=header)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(snkr.content,'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('tr', class_="srrowns"):
    print(item.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.a)
```

prints:

```
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-6712/" title="CVE-2017-6712 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-6712</a>
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-6708/" title="CVE-2017-6708 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-6708</a>
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-6707/" title="CVE-2017-6707 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-6707</a>
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-1269/" title="CVE-2017-1269 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-1269</a>
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-0711/" title="CVE-2017-0711 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-0711</a>
<a href="/cve/CVE-2017-0706/" title="CVE-2017-0706 security vulnerability details">CVE-2017-0706</a>
```

using the recommened string:

```
print(item.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.a.href)
```

prints:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

can't figure out how to extract the `/cve/CVE-2017-XXXX/` parts. purhaps i've gone about it the wrong way. i dont need the titles or html, just the uri's.

Comment: It's `['href']` not `.href`... The idea in bs is `.tag` and `['attribute']`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like:

```
for item in soup.find_all('tr', class_="srrowns"):
    print(item.td.next_sibling.next_sibling.a['href'])
```